# Generate a table on Google slides from large dataset

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

Going from a dataset (on csv), I would like to generate automatically a table on Google slides. The issue is how can I make sure that if some cells overflow, then they would be cut and added on a new slide. Thanks a lot for your help.

I didn't find any useful resources or how to slides docs.